# Is the file created by child after fork, also shared with parent?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

I know that after `fork()`, all files (and their offsets) opened by the **parent** are shared
by the **child**. That is, **parent** and **child** share the file table entry of all the files.

What happens if **child** opens some file. Is it specific to **child**? Or is it shared by **parent**?

I've also written small test program. Is this the right way to test this?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FLAG (O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        int fc;
        if ((fc = open("abc", FLAG)) == -1) {
            perror("cannot open abc");
            exit(-1);
        }
        exit(fc);
        //returning the file descriptor open through exit()
    } else {
        int fp;
        wait(&fp);
        if (fp == -1)
            exit(1);
        if (fcntl(fp, F_GETFD) == -1)
            perror("doesn't work");     //Ouputs: doesn't work: Bad file descriptor
        //returns file descriptor flags
        //should not return error, if fd is valid
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: To make it short: **no**. Child gets a snapshot of parent's handles in the moment of the fork, everything will happen after that won't be reflected.

Comment: @MM. I'm opening file in child after `fork` not before as the cited question does.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question [Are file descriptors shared when forking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277289/are-file-descriptors-shared-when-forking) as has been suggested.  That asks about file descriptors opened before forking; this asks about file descriptors created after forking.  The situations and answers are quite different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The child gets a copy of the file descriptors of the parent in the moment of `fork()`.

If you open a file in the child, it's not shared with the parent.

Also if you open a file in the parent process after `fork()` it won't be shared with the child.

Answer (score 0):

All remaining open file will be closed when your child process exits. So, it is no more valid when the parent try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[man fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) :

> The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file
>   descriptors.
>   Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open file
>   description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor in the
>   parent.  This means that the two descriptors share open file status
>   flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes (see the
>   description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).

If you close a file in the child, it will also been closed in parent.

Comment: when child exits, all files are closed. since parent `stdout` is also shared, why is that not closed?

Comment: what function do you use to close all file descriptors ?

Comment: I mean does normal exit close all files?

Comment: No it doesn't. Depending on your os and it's configuration, the files will be automatically closed or not. On linux file descriptor are closed after process ending most of time, but if the file descriptor is still used by another process, it won't be closed.

Comment: but i would like to knwo if in the live time of the child the parent process can see the file descriptor opened by the child

Answer (score 0):

I have this code and i saw the file descriptors are shared with parent pid

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


pid_t p;

int main(){
    if((p = fork()) != -1){
            open("file",O_APPEND);
            sleep(120);
    }
}

gcc -o fork fork.c

root      4576  2675  0 06:39 ttyS0    00:00:00 ./fork
root      4577  4576  0 06:39 ttyS0    00:00:00 ./fork

lsof -p 4576
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
fork    4576 root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 69266 /root
fork    4576 root  rtd    DIR    8,1     4096     2 /
fork    4576 root  txt    REG    8,1     9882 70117 /root/fork
fork    4576 root  mem    REG    8,1  1682436 23185 /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
fork    4576 root  mem    REG    8,1   143987 23174 /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
fork    4576 root    0u   CHR   4,64      0t0  3340 /dev/ttyS0
fork    4576 root    1u   CHR   4,64      0t0  3340 /dev/ttyS0
fork    4576 root    2u   CHR   4,64      0t0  3340 /dev/ttyS0
fork    4576 root    3r   REG    8,1        0 75269 /root/file

lsof -p 4577
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
fork    4577 root  cwd    DIR    8,1     4096 69266 /root
fork    4577 root  rtd    DIR    8,1     4096     2 /
fork    4577 root  txt    REG    8,1     9882 70117 /root/fork
fork    4577 root  mem    REG    8,1  1682436 23185 /lib/libc-2.11.3.so
fork    4577 root  mem    REG    8,1   143987 23174 /lib/ld-2.11.3.so
fork    4577 root    0u   CHR   4,64      0t0  3340 /dev/ttyS0
fork    4577 root    1u   CHR   4,64      0t0  3340 /dev/ttyS0
fork    4577 root    2u   CHR   4,64      0t0  3340 /dev/ttyS0
fork    4577 root    3r   REG    8,1        0 75269 /root/file
```

The same result using this python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time

print os.getpid()

if os.fork() is not None:
  print os.getpid()
  fd = open("/etc/passwd","r")
  time.sleep(120)
```

Now you can check the parent and child process:

```
python pyfork.py
25131
25131
25132

lsof -p 25131
......
......
......
python  25131 root    3r   REG    8,8      2080  143680 /etc/passwd

lsof -p 25131
......
......
......
python  25132 root    3r   REG    8,8      2080  143680 /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Your lsof output shows that each process happens to have a file descriptor open to the same file (NODE).  It does *not* tell you that they are sharing an open file description.

Comment: Well, yes and no.  The lsof output you posted has a column named NODE, which is what I meant to draw your attention to.  The meaning of values in that field is the file's inode.

Comment: why process 4576 see file descriptor 3 if i open the /root/file inside the child?

Comment: There's a bug in your code: fork() returns 0 in the child and pid of the child in the parent process. For both parent and child your condition will be true so they will both open the same file.

Comment: @xyz I don't think is bug in my C code, I wrote in python and the problem is the same, file descriptor open after fork, is shared with the parent process, I think this happen because the parent and child use the same file descriptor table.

Comment: It is a bug, in Python os.fork() doesn't return None. Check the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork

Comment: @xyz is not depending about my code, you can try to use the code you want and you well see, the files opened for the child process is shared with parent.

Comment: It is your code, this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/664ac598d34bff862019 works fine.