# Difference between fclose and close

Tags: c, file, posix, file-descriptor

If I `fopen` a file, what's the difference between calling `fclose` or `close` and which one should I use?

If forked children have access to the file as well, what should they do when they are finished with the file?

Comment: One more thing to remember. C FILE* streams use buffered I/O internally. fclose() flushes this buffer and then closes the file descriptor at OS level. close()'ing a FILE* stream may not flush this internal buffer and you may lose data. So for C streams always use C fxxx() functions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fclose()` is function related with *file streams*. When you open file with the help of `fopen()` and assign stream to `FILE *ptr`. Then you will use `fclose()` to close the opened file.

`close()` is a function related with *file descriptors*. When you open file with the help of `open()` and assign descriptor to `int fd`. Then you will use `close()` to close the opened file.

The functions like `fopen()`, `fclose()` etc are *C standard functions*, while the other category of `open()`, `close()` etc are POSIX-specific. This means that code written with `open()`, `close()` etc is not a standard C code and hence non-portable. Whereas the code written with `fopen()`, `fclose` etc is a standard code and can be ported on any type of system.

> which one should I use?

It depends on how you opened the file. If you open a file with `fopen()`, you should use `fclose()` and if you open file with `open()`, you should use `close()`.

> If forked children have access to the file as well, what should they do when they are finished with the file?

This is also dependent on where you made the `fork()` call: before opening the file or after opening it.

See: [Are file descriptors shared when fork()ing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277289/are-file-descriptors-shared-when-forking?rq=1)

See: `man fclose` and `man close`

Comment: A file descriptor can also be closed by using `fclose()` if a file steam has been created by `fdopen()`. `The file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream created by fdopen() is closed.` Source: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen

Answer (score 1):

`open()` and `close()` are UNIX syscalls which return and take file descriptors, for use with other UNIX syscalls such as `write()`. `fopen()` and `fclose()` are standard C library functions which operate on `FILE*`s, for use with things like `fwrite` and `fprintf`. The latter are almost always what you should be using: They're simpler and more cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, forked children have the same numeric file descriptor as the parent, but it's a copy; they can close it, and it will still be open for the parent and other children. (Though personally, I don't like to have files open when I `fork()`... I like to make that sort of shared resource usage explicit. Pipes, of course, are an exception.)

Answer (score 0):

> which one should I use?

If you open a file with `fopen`, close it with `fclose`. Using `close` in this case may cause a memory leak on a handle allocated by `fopen`