# Why does writing to an inherited file handle from a python sub-process result in not all rows being written?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have the following python program, which starts three processes that each write 10000 random rows to the same file using an inherited file handle:

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import string
import traceback

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # clear out the file first
  open('out.txt', 'w')
  # initialise file handle to be inherited by sub-processes
  file_handle = open('out.txt', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
  process_count = 3

# routine to be run by sub-processes
# adds n lines to the file
def write_random_rows(n):
  try:
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    for _ in range(n):
      s = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(100))
      file_handle.write(s+"\n")
  except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # initialise the multiprocessing pool
  process_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=process_count)

  # write the rows
  for i in range(process_count):
    process_pool.apply_async(write_random_rows, (10000,))
    # write_random_rows(10000)

  # wait for the sub-processes to finish
  process_pool.close()
  process_pool.join()
```

As a result of running this, I expect the file to contain **30000** rows. If I run `write_random_rows(10000)` inside my main loop (the commented out line in the above program), 30000 rows are written to the file as expected. However, if I run the non-commented line, `process_pool.apply_async(write_random_rows, (10000,))`, I end up with **15498** rows in the file.

Strangely, no matter how many times I rerun this script, I always get the same (incorrect) number of rows in the output file.

I can fix this issue by initializing the file handle from within `write_random_rows()`, i.e. within the sub-process execution, which suggests that somehow the inherited file handles are interfering with each other. If it was related to some kind of race condition though, I would expect the number of rows to change each time I ran the script. Why exactly does this issue occur?

Comment: Running on Linux with Python 3.5 I get 29766 rows, instead of 15498, though it is consistent for me, even across a couple of different computers. If I change the contents of the lines (specifically the length of them) I get a different value though! This suggests some sort of race condition. Why it is so consistent is a bit curious though.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and I also consistently get 29766 rows of output (with both Python 3.6 and 3.7). Curiously, even dropping down to `process_count = 1` results in some lines going missing!

Comment: @Josh That seems really strange. It would be interesting to rewrite this in C/C++ and see if the behaviour is reproducible there as well, or if it is something Python introduces. If testing with C/C++ it would be feasible to compare threads and fork() as well.

Comment: @Vorpal @Josh For Python >=3.5 at least, the consistency of the data dropped can be explained exactly (eg @Josh I expect you lost 78 lines when you used `process_count = 1` ... see my answer for details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is due to a combination of:

- fork copying the file descriptor from parent to child; and
- buffering; and
- the lack of an implicit flush as each child exits

Forking processes results in the parent and child **sharing** a posix file descriptor.  In the presence of raw writes this should **not** result in data loss, but without any form of synchronisation between parent and child it always results in scrambled interleaving of data.

However in the presence of independent buffering by the processes, data may be lost depending on how the buffered write is implemented.

So ... a useful experiment in this case would involve replicating your problem with **no** buffering involved. This could be done in two ways:

- using an `open(..., mode='ab', buffering=0)` ... and then as this is a binary file ensuring that all writes encode to `bytes` using

  ```
  file_handle.write(bytes(s+"\n", encoding="utf-8"))
  ```

  Doing so results in a file with 30,000 lines of size 3030000 bytes (as expected)
- jump through some hoops to open the file as as an `io.TextIOWrapper` with non-default options that disable the buffering.  We are unable to control the flags we need via `open` so instead create it as:

  ```
  file_handle = io.TextIOWrapper(
      io.BufferedWriter(
          io.FileIO("out.txt", mode="a"),
          buffer_size=1),
      newline='', encoding="utf-8", 
      write_through=True)
  ```

  This will also result in a file of 30,000 lines of size 3030000 bytes (as expected)

On Python 3.7, as commenters have noted, the original code results in a file with 29,766 lines rather than 30,000.  This is 78 lines short per worker.  Running that code with two workers produces a file with 19,844 lines (which is also 78 lines short per worker).

Why?  It is standard practice to exit a forked child process using `os._exit` and it appears that this is **not** flushing the remaining buffer in each child to disk ... this explains the missing 78 lines per child **exactly**.

- On my machine, the default buffer size (`io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`) is 8192 bytes.
- Each line consists of 101 bytes.  This means the buffer will overrun and be flushed every `ceil(8192 / 101) = 82` lines. That is, 81 lines will almost fill the buffer and the 82nd line will cause the preceding 81 lines and itself to be flushed.
- Thus, after 10,000 iterations we have `10,000 % 82 = 78` lines remaining in the buffer in each child.

Thus it would appear the missing data is buffered data that has **not** been flushed.  So, making the following change:

```
def write_random_rows(n):
    ...
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()

    # flush the file
    file_handle.flush()
```

will result in the desired 30,000 lines.

**NOTE:**

In either case, it is almost always better to ensure a child process is **not** sharing a file handle by either deferring the open to the child, or `dup`'ing any open file handles across a fork.

Answer (score 3):

File descriptors and their positions are shared across fork() on POSIX systems,  as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277326/11939043). That is likely to cause all sorts of issues when writing concurrently. It is indeed curious that it is so consistent from run to run though.

It makes sense that is reliable when using separate file descriptors though. POSIX [guarantees this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) when using O_APPEND.

Comment: Sharing a file descriptor is indeed bad ... but we need to throw in a little more before we can cause data loss

Answer (score 0):

since your workers are running in parallel they are "fighting" for the same resource 'file_handle', they are overwriting same rows

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't this happen then if I open a new file handle in each process? Shouldn't the process of forking copy the file handle to each individual process rather than using some kind of shared handle? If this was the case also, I'd expect to see the number of rows change in the resulting file since which process "wins" the contention ought to be non-deterministic.